# How do I serialise a mesh to a text file?

Tags: terrain, mesh, file, serialization, content-generation

I'm building a game engine in OpenTK (OpenGL for C#). Is it ossible to take a terrain mesh (in any format) and convert it into a text file (or a really small character-filled file, no more than a few bytes). Then, afterwards, I'd take that file and generate the terrain from it.

The only reason I'm doing this is to save some memory on the computer. I think it would be more efficient if we had to quickly generate a crude terrain, and then smooth it instead of loading in a large mesh file.

Is this possible, and if so, how could I do it?

Comment: Take a look at the .obj model files they are essentially what you are looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the [obj file format](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) is what you need. OBJ is pretty commonly used in 3D graphics, and it's a text file. You will need to walk through your mesh properties and write your own file. Then you'll be able to [load and display it](http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-7-model-loading/).

Comment: Glad it helped. And thank you, @jhocking for the edit.